# HDD downsize after installing ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem

here is the big deal guys i was using windows with two partitions "C:" and "D:". After installing ubuntu "D:" partition is gone but totally gone -.- there was 500gb before installing ubuntu but i have just 298 gb hdd space so what can I do guys:

[image]

Comment: http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/5301/1u79.png  i see just nothing bro

Comment: The image says that your harddrive is only 300GB. You sure it is not another drive?

Comment: Yep, you must have two drives rather than just having had two partitions on one drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a separate C: and D: suggests there might be two physical drives.

From what I see above, you have a Root partition of 243MB in **/dev/sda1**, and then an ubuntu-vg LVM partition of 298GB, **/dev/sda5**, within the extended partition **/dev/sda2**. I would, very carefully, examine what's in **/dev/sda5** and copy anything you want to save to an external drive, then delete (in this order) **/dev/sda5**, **/dev/sda2**, save the change, then expand **/dev/sda1** to fill almost the entire drive, leaving room (2GB? 4GB? However much your RAM size is) for the swap partition.

After you have set **/dev/sda1** to roughly 294-296 GB and created the /dev/sda5 swap (inside an extended partition **/dev/sda2**), save again.

Then, check what's in **/dev/sdb** by clicking on the spin box at upper left which now says `/dev/sda 298.09GB` for I suspect the 500GB drive is really **/dev/sdb** and **/dev/sda** is a 300GB drive.

Comment: okay bro  i just found the problem my little brother changed his hdd with mine and didnt tell me anyway its really 300gb now we are sure about it and i did your suggestions it looks more stable now about partitions thank you for your help.

Comment: What can you say abt little brothers which can be reprinted in an open forum?